# Как извлечь запросом размер массива по ключу?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

Есть таблица:

```
create table PARAM (
    ID VARCHAR2(30), DOCUMENT blob)
```

Столбец `Document` хранит JSON вида:

```
{"id":"value","parameters":[{...},{...},{...}]}
```

Как извлечь запросом размер массива параметров?

Нужно извлечь размер массива для каждой записи в таблице, а затем просуммировать все эти значения.

Например, хотелось бы получить:

```
    ID    ARRAY_SIZE
    ----  ----------
    1     10
    2     0
    3     3

    TOTAL_RECORDS   TOTAL_ARRAYS_SIZE
    -------------   -----------------
    3               13
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Get array size in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64769927) от участника [@neo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8564249/neo)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64769927

Answer (score 2):

При условии, что на столбце есть `CHECK` ограничение `IS ISON`, то можно воспользоваться методом `size()` для получения количества элементов в массиве:

```
create table t (
    c1 int, c2 blob check (c2 is json))
/    
insert into t values ( 1, '{ "arr" : [1, 2, 3] }');
insert into t values ( 2, '{ "arr" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }');
insert into t values ( 2, '{ "arr" : [] }');
commit;

select count(*) count, sum (a.c2.arr.size()) total from t a;

     COUNT      TOTAL
---------- ----------
         3          8
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63151590) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>